# nodejs doesn't consistently fire 'data' event on successful POST from Java program

Tags: java, json, http, node.js, post

I wrote some code to periodically post data to a NodeJs program that listens for the POST and prints the data.  However, sometimes on the header makes it through and sometimes both the header and the body make it through.  Here's the Java code that's posting the data:

```
JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject();
dataObject.put("test", "true");
URLConnection urlConn = thisSubUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.setDoInput (true);
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
String dataStr = dataObject.toString();
wr.write(dataStr, 0, dataStr.length());
wr.flush();
wr.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
in.close();
```

The server code looks like this:

```
var server= http.createServer(function(req,res){
req.setEncoding('utf8');
console.log(req.headers);
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
          console.log("Receive_Event::" + chunk);
         });
req.on('end', function() {
    console.log('on end');
});

console.log("Bytes received: " + req.socket.bytesRead);
if(req.method=='POST'){
    handlePost(req,res);
} else{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end();
}
}).listen(1338, "127.0.0.1");
```

The header is always printed out.  The number of bytes received varies in length, between the number of the bytes in the header and the number of bytes in the header + the body length.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The event is consistently fired using command-line curl.  I'm not sure what's going wrong with POSTing from java.

Comment: do you see 'on end' before receiving all headers and post body? I think you should buffer all data and call handlePost in 'end' event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening is that you will emit the `res.end()` (don't know what `handlePost` actually does) before you have received all the "data" chunks. You should call all the extra logic in the "end" event

```
var server= http.createServer(function(req,res){
    req.setEncoding('utf8');

    console.log(req.headers);

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log("Receive_Event::" + chunk);
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        console.log('on end');
        console.log("Bytes received: " + req.socket.bytesRead);
        if(req.method=='POST'){
            handlePost(req,res);
        } else{
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end();
        }
    });


}).listen(1338, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: That's exactly right.  It occurred to me right after I posted that that's precisely what was happening.  Thanks for the quick reply!